# onResume to restart playing background music is not working

Tags: java, android, onresume, onpause, background-music

this is my first app so this question/answer might be pretty basic.
I currently have onPause(); , to stop the music playing when player leaves the screen. I've tried to do a similar thing but with onResume, so that the music plays again (backgroundMusic). Unfortunately this isn't working. It does work again when I press the reset button or go back to the home page and come back to the game page. But it just doesn't load as soon as the app is back on screen, like I would like it to.

My code excerpt follows;

```
package com.example.android.buttongame;
```

...

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
...

MediaPlayer winningSound;
MediaPlayer buttonSound;
MediaPlayer backgroundMusic;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    /*
    Plays ticking background noise at the start of this activity. Set on a loop
     */

backgroundMusic = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.ticking_background);

    backgroundMusic.start();
    backgroundMusic.setOnErrorListener(new android.media.MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener() {

        public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mediaplayer, int i, int j)
        {
            return false;
        }
    });
    backgroundMusic.setLooping(true);


}

@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    backgroundMusic.start();
}

public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    backgroundMusic.stop();
}



...

public void reset(View v) {

     /*
        Plays button sound
         */
    buttonSound = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.button_sound);
    buttonSound.start();

    /*
     * Refreshes activity
     */

   this.recreate();

}
```

...
    public void homePage (View view) {

```
     /*
        Stops background music
         */

    backgroundMusic.stop();

     /*
        Plays button sound
         */
    buttonSound = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.button_sound);
    buttonSound.start();

    /*
    Leads to home page
     */
    Intent homePage = new Intent(this, HomePage.class);
    startActivity(homePage);
}
```

}

Comment: Can you add some logs to your program please: most importantly in the backgroundMusic onErrorListener so that you can see if any errors are raised there and what they are, and in the onResume handler to check that it is actually being called? If for some reason you're not allowed to do this, you could start the music in a later event in the lifecycle or you could retry the start music after a short delay, e.g. 100ms. But by silently eating an error you may well be getting you're losing valuable information!

Comment: Thanks, Ghulam's answer worked for me. But I will look into doing that for future problems

Answer (score 1):

At the place of `backgroundMusic.stop()`, you should use `backgroundMusic.pause()` then you will achieve what you are looking for.

Calling `stop()` stops playback and causes a `MediaPlayer` in the **Started**, **Paused**, **Prepared** or **PlaybackCompleted** state to enter the **Stopped** state.
Once in the **Stopped** state, playback cannot be started until `prepare()` or `prepareAsync()` are called to set the `MediaPlayer` object to the **Prepared** state again.
Calling `stop()` has no effect on a `MediaPlayer` object that is already in the **Stopped** state.

Here is the documentation of `MediaPlayer` that will help you to understand about its **API**s.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer

Comment: Thank you so much! This was so simple, but worked for me :)